# Fabric.js - Attach object creation to mouse click

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

When you create a new fabric object, you can specify the location for it to appear on the canvas. Is there a way to attach the generated object to the mouse and then place the object on click (or touch)?

E.g. way to generate a circle which appears on the canvas.

```
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 20, fill: 'green', left: 100, top: 100
});
```

Comment: @kangax - any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's fairly easy to update the position of an object to match that of the mouse's position and on `mouse:up` clone that object and place it on the canvas.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var mousecursor = new fabric.Circle({ 
  left: 0, 
  top: 0, 
  radius: 5, 
  fill: '#9f9', 
  originX: 'right', 
  originY: 'bottom',
})

canvas.add(mousecursor);

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(obj) {
  mousecursor.top = obj.e.y - mousecursor.radius;
  mousecursor.left = obj.e.x - mousecursor.radius;
  canvas.renderAll()
})

canvas.on('mouse:out', function(obj) {
  // put circle off screen
  mousecursor.top = -100;
  mousecursor.left = -100;
  canvas.renderAll()
})

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(obj) {
  canvas.add(mousecursor.clone())
  canvas.renderAll()
})
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Perfect! Sorry I forgot to accept this answer earlier.

Comment: Thanks! do you have an example that will take canvas pan and zoom into account?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var mousecursor = new fabric.Circle({ 
  left: 0, 
  top: 0, 
  radius: 50, 
  fill: '#9f9', 
  originX: 'right', 
  originY: 'bottom',
})

canvas.add(mousecursor);
   
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(obj) {
  mousecursor.top = obj.e.y;
  mousecursor.left = obj.e.x;
  canvas.renderAll()
})
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```